# Противоположные примеры с "ну"

Tags: пунктуация

В статье на Грамоте про ["ну"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D1%83&all=x) нашёл **подряд** (!) примеры с *ну* с противоположной пунктуацией. В одном случае запятая есть, в другом нет, хотя в обоих случаях *ну* продолжает только глагол в 3-м лице: *"Ну, придумала! Ну насмешил".* Почему так странно? Заметил в первом "!", но он же не может быть решающим, если и во втором случае *ну* тоже является междометием.

Comment: Артем, меня тоже удивили такие знаки препинания. Может, Вам обратиться к ним. Я тоже попытаюсь обратиться к ним, просто они не поймешь, на какие вопросы отвечают. Даже не уверен, что ответят. но попытка не пытка.

Comment: Точно, спасибо за совет, Серж! Только действительно не знаки препинания удивляют, а то, что во втором случае "ну" тоже отнесли к междометиям. Мне когда-то ответили на почту с Грамоты, и я потом посылал им раз или два письмо об опечатке в статье, и мне отвечали и правили статью (вроде это всё-таки было один раз). Так что можно туда и написать. Только давайте договоримся, кто напишет, чтобы два раза не получилось одно и то же.)) Если Вы захотите написать, я Вам адрес тот дам. Ну и конечно, отпишитесь тогда тут, пожалуйста, насчёт их ответа.

Comment: Артем, я уже написал. Если через какое-то время они не ответят, можете (если захотите), самим попытаться. Только Вы уверены, что на Грамоту обращались? Почему спрашиваю: обычно на почту отвечает Грамма.ру, а не Грамота. От грамоты.ру на почту приходит только оповещение об ответе.

Comment: Да, Грамота, не Грамма.ру, проверил (хотя и не сомневался). Оказывается, на сайте есть этот адрес, так что я думаю, его можно выложить: portal@gramota.ru. C него мне два раза (как я только что посмотрел) отвечали, что исправили опечатки и даже благодарили. :)

Comment: Может, удалить вопрос, когда они ответят, как считаете? А то я может им репутацию этим чуть-чуть порчу...

Comment: Абсолютно. Вы задали интересный вопрос. Если получим ответ, выложим сюда. Я тоже ведь собирался ответить на ваш вопрос, так же, как Людмила, если бы внимательно не прочитал бы все примеры в словаре. Ксати, в справочники по пунктуации ( составитель Грамота.ру), дано точно то правило, на которое ориентировалась Людмила, и я. На нашем портале были подобные вопросы.

Comment: Артем, Грамота не ответила, как всегда! Но я задал Грамме.ру и они ответили.

Comment: См.ниже, я написал. Грамоте, видимо, нечего было сказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ### Ответ Граммы.ру

Вопрос о разграничении "ну"-частицы и "ну"-междометия не вполне понятен. Справочники обычно указывают на наиболее ясные случаи и обходят стороной ситуации, когда в одинаковом контексте "ну" может быть употреблено и как частица, и как междометие. Ваш вопрос можно свести к следующей проблеме: может ли "ну" в сочетании с личной формой глагола использоваться в обеих функциях (частицы и междометия).
В справочной литературе ответ на этот вопрос отсутствует. Обращение к Национальному корпусу русского языка показывает, что в большинстве случаев редакторы и корректоры предпочитают определять "ну" в позиции перед личной формой глагола как междометие и отделять ее запятой от глагола:
Ну, разойдутся через год, ну и бог с ними". [Юрий Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)];
Овца легла на землю, задерганная верёвкой. ― Ну, посвети. Я отдал фонарь и наклонился над человеком, пластом лежащим на земле. [Юрий Коваль. Гроза над картофельным полем (1974)];
Первый раз в жизни. Ну, выпили немного ― разговорились. Заспорили. [Василий Шукшин. Печки-лавочки (1970-1972)];
Ну, посиди со мной! ― она силой посадила меня на табуретку. ― Посиди, поговорим о жизни. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Леди Макбет (1970)]

Однако некоторые редакторы и корректоры считают, что "ну" в этой позиции может использоваться и как усилительная частица, например:
― Копай яму, ― сказал Булыга и плюнул мимо Шурки. ― Ну выкопаю, ну и что? Шурка прошёлся по поляне вокруг сосны, потыкал лопатой. [Юрий Коваль. У Кривой сосны (1979)] ;
Поэтому солдат только пригрозил: «Ну подожди же!» И отошёл от глазка. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 4 (1978)];
Как только вышли на улицу и отошли на безопасное расстояние, я ему сказал: "Ну начинай. Гитлер входит в бомбоубежище, а там…" [Фазиль Искандер. Летним днем (1969)].

Таким образом, "ну" может быть употреблено перед глаголом и как частица, и как междометие, а значит, разграничение этих случаев во  многом опирается на произвол автор (или корректора). При их разграничении учитывается степень связанности "ну" и глагола, наличие самостоятельного ударения у "ну" и паузы между ним и последующим словом.

> **Междометие оформляет междометную фразу, поэтому, разумеется, должно обособляться. Там явная ошибка.**

С уважением
GRAMMA.RU

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. В который раз удивляюсь насколько выразителен, но в то же время сложен русский язык. Слово "НУ" вроде всего то состоит из двух букв, но в скольких "фантиках" его можно завернуть. Выделил интонацией - один смысл, не выделил - другой смысл. Как дети все это понимают. Интуитивно наверное.

Answer (score 4):

"Ну" может быть междометием, а может быть частицей - как произнесёте. какой смысл вложите.

"Ну, придумала!-междометие, выражающее удивление.

"Ну насмешил."- усилительная частица.Можно ещё усилить:"Ну и насмешил!"

В другой ситуации можно использовать и как междометие удивления: "НУ, насмешил"или: "Ну?!Насмешил".

Междометие выражает побуждение и удивление и выделяется паузой при произнесении, частица интонационно не отделяется от последующих слов.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Только Грамота-то выдаёт оба случая за междометия!