# Чем является и что выражает слово "НУ" в нижеуказанных предложениях?

Tags: значение-слов, семантика

1. Это задачу никто не решил в нашем классе. Ну кроме меня.
2. Миша совсем не изменился. Ну, если только вырос немного.
3. Ну, если это действительно правда, тогда я согласен вам помочь.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419933/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D1%83

Comment: Пройдите по ссылке. Прочитайте ответ Граммы.ру.

Answer (score 1):

Это междометие.

> незнаменательная часть речи, неизменяемое слово или словосочетание, служащее для нерасчлененного выражения чувства, ощущения или душевного состояния

Выражает оно в этих случаях задумчивость и близко по значению к формулировке "хотя, если подумать", кроме третьего случая. Там ближе по смыслу к слову "ладно". В любом случае "ну" сопровождает некоторую уступку со стороны говорящего — уступку: логике, фактам, аргументам.

**Дополнение**. Вариант, предложенный пользователем Sharon, считаю неверным. Это не никак не тот случай, который описан ниже:

> Употр. при усилении выразительности, при подчеркивании значения того или иного слова.

Этот случай хорошо подходит к следующей фразе:

> Ну кроме меня хоть кто-то решит задание-то, а?
>
> Почему вы сказали, что никто не решил задание? Ну я же сделал!

В вопросе (в предложении 1) другой случай. рассказчик сообщает информацию: "НИКТО не решил задачу". То есть ВООБЩЕ никто. Это законченная мысль, не подразумевающая исключений и оговорок. Но абсолютизм этого утверждения "уступает" новому тезису: "но вообще-то не никто, ведь я решил". Это "вообще-то" заключено в единственном "Ну". Разворачивать его можно в разные фразы: "хотя надо признать", "но если быть до конца честным", "ну если поразмыслить" и др. Это всё выражает задумчивость и признание рассказчиком необходимости скорректировать первую мысль оговоркой.

Без паузы это выражение, как я его вижу, несёт более активный, если угодно, агрессивный характер. Так усиливают фразы, в чём смысла не вижу. Моё мнение: запятая просто пропущена по ошибке. Без неё эта фраза бестолкова. Там явно задумчивость. Усиление может быть в других предложениях, как в моих примерах выше. Там да. А здесь оговорка, а не эмоциональная фраза.

Так что правильно поставить запятую и определить "ну" как междометие.

Comment: "В любом случае "ну" сопровождает некоторую уступку со стороны говорящего — уступку: логике, фактам, аргументам" - не совсем понял причем здесь уступка? К примеру, в первом предложении кто кому (или что чему) уступает?

Comment: Мне кажется в первом предложении "НУ" не выражает задумчивость, т.к произносится без паузы. Здесь что-то другое.

Comment: @user189361 перенёс свои ответы Вам из комментария в дополненный ответ.

Comment: С задумчивостью все понятно. Но в первом предложении паузы нет, запятая не пропущена и "Ну кроме меня" произносится практически слитно, зачем тогда нужно ставить запятую? И согласны ли вы с Sharon в части побуждения к продолжению речи?

Comment: @user189361 дело в том, что я не согласен с тем .что там нет паузы. Если я читаю с паузой, выходит уточнение. Если без паузы, то восклицание по типу моего примера. Я железно держусь позиции, что это принципиально разные фразы, и в контексте предложения из вопроса может быть только пауза с запятой. По части того, что "ну" связывает две мысли, я с Sharon согласен. Только побуждение тут не при чём. Побуждающее "ну" это когда ты подошёл к человеку, окликнувшему тебя, и говоришь ему: "Ну?", мол, говори, что хотел.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что это во всех случаях это **частица с усилительным значением.**

Основным значением слова НУ является побуждение к каким-то действиям, но в данном случае это побуждение **к продолжению речи, чтобы обратить внимание на исключения, несоответствие сказанному** (предложения 1 и 2) или **на условие** последующего действия (предложение 3)

Частица обособляется при наличии **паузы**, но предложения 2 и 3 можно произнести и без паузы. Но это **не междометие**. Междометие выражает чувства, волеизъявление, понукание, но ничего этого здесь нет.

**Значение слова НУ в Толковом словаре Ефремовой**

1. **предикатив разг.**

1) а) Побуждение к чему-л. как действие.б) Понуканиие как действие.2) Выражение удивления, негодования, иронии, восхищения и других чувств как действие. 3) Выражение волеизъявления .

2. **союз разг**.Употр. при указании на вывод, заключение или замечание.

**3. частица разг.** 1) Употр. при выражении сомнения, удивления, недоверия; соответствует по значению сл.: 2) Употр. при ответе на обращение; соответствует по значению сл.: что? а что?

**3) Употр. при усилении выразительности, при подчеркивании значения того или иного слова.**

**4. межд. разг.** 1) а) Употр. при побуждении к действию. б) Употр. при понукании;  2) Употр. при выражении удивления, негодования, иронии, восхищения и других чувств. 3) Употр. при выражении волеизъявления; соответствует по значению сл.:

Comment: Ещё междометие "ну" может выражать задумчивость, а это актуально для предложений 2 и 3. В самом вопросе уже есть ответ - частица там, где нет запятой.

Comment: Да, может выражать глубокую задумчивость, особенно в форме "ну это". Такое же значение имеют слова "короче" и "типа".

Comment: Что-то не вижу такого значения у этих слов. "*Типа*" указывает на примерность (*вроде*), но не на размышление (было бы обособление). Конечно, после них можно три точки поставить (задумчивость после любого слова). Сейчас "*ну*" часто используют не как глубокую задумчивость, а как небольшую (похоже на сокращение от "*ну если поразмыслить*").

Comment: А не служит ли "НУ" в 1-м и 2-м предложениях для уточнения предыдущего высказывания?

Comment: Если "НУ" побуждает, то согласно Ефремовой - это междометие. Или я не прав?

Answer (score 1):

1) Мы часто используем в устной речи слово ***ну***, как бы *понукаем* себя или других, **побуждаем к действию**.

Часто это действие относится **к продолжению речи**. Вот пример.

*Ты пойдешь на каток? — Пока не знаю, подумаю.*

***Ну*** ты пойдешь на каток? (уже решил?). — *Пока еще думаю.*

***Ну,*** ты пойдешь на каток (говори, наконец, что решил?). — Ну ладно, пойду (я подумал и решил).

Значение ***ну*** в эти фразах в принципе одно и то же, но при обособлении и выделении паузой частица ***ну*** условно переходит в междометие ***ну*** (это уже побуждение **к реальной речи**).

2) **Ответы на вопросы**

*Это задачу никто не решил в нашем классе. Ну кроме меня.*

Частица ***ну*** обозначает **необходимость дополнения** к ранее сказанному, так как основное сообщение не является точным. Говорящий быстро осознает это, поэтому паузы нет.

*Миша совсем не изменился. Ну, если только вырос немного.*

Здесь ситуация аналогичная, но пауза подчеркивает сам процесс размышления: необходимое дополнение осознается не сразу.

*Ну, если это действительно правда, тогда я согласен вам помочь.*

Здесь ***ну*** обозначает обдуманность решения и указывает на аргумент, повлиявший на него.

**Вывод:**  Таким образом, при сходной семантике частица ***ну*** отличается от междометия ***ну*** достаточно условно.

Comment: Sharon, я думаю, что вы с Третьим глазом, говорите об одном и том же, но разными словами. Что в сухом остатке - это побуждение к речи с целью дополнить, уточнить (1 и 2 предложения), а также выражение обдуманности или задумчивости (3 предложение). Причем, если "НУ" связано с задумчивостью, то обязательно должна ставиться запятая. Так ли?

Comment: В сухом остатке мы имеем следующее:   НУ показывает, что перед нами  ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ речи, обусловленное какими-либо причинами ( надо получить ответ, уточнить сказанное, согласиться с чем-либо ранее предложенным и т.д.).