# Использование частицы Ну

Tags: семантика

Если говорить о междометиях, то всё, что говорится с ними, можно сказать и без них, только с нужной интонацией либо неоднозначностью. То есть междометия устраняют лишние смыслы и выделяют нужный нам. **Междометия не вносят нового смысла в предложение, а лишь выделяют один из уже имеющихся.** Междометия всегда можно опустить, в расчете что слушатель сам додумается какая именно эмоциональная окраска и какой смысл у предложения.

Верно ли все то же относительно частицы "ну"? Существуют ли предложения, добавление частицы "ну" в которые, добавляет **новый** смысл в предложение, а не просто выделяет один из уже имеющихся смыслов в предложении без частицы "ну"?

Примеры без нового смысла:

> Ну, погоди! = Погоди! Еще посмотрим чья возьмет!
>
> Нуу, не знаю = Не знаю
>
> Ну, может быть = Может быть
>
> Ну, пошел! = Пошел!
>
> Ну же, скоро? = скоро?

Придумались такие примеры, вроде с новым смыслом:

> 1. Нуу, знаете ли... ! = Знаете ли
> 2. Нуу вы поняли! = Вы поняли.

В 1. это скорее крылатое выражение, поэтому там и возникает новый смысл.
В 2. действительно новый смысл, соответствующий "В общем, вы поняли".

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419933/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d1%83  Повтор вопроса.

Comment: Никак не связано с моим вопросом. Я спрашивал есть ли добавочный смысл у слова "ну". Такой смысл чтобы добавление частицы принципиально бы меняло смысл предложения.